# Decoding zip file returned from MS Graph API as content Bytes

Tags: python

I have a connection to an organization's mailbox. Using the MS Graph API, the response from the API returns the given message's attachment as content bytes. The issue I'm having is that the attachment is within a `.zip`. There is only 1 file in the `.zip` which is of type `.txt`

So with just the `.txt` file as the attachment not in the `.zip` the `content-bytes` returned is

```
dGhpcyBpcyBzb21lIHRlc3QgdGV4dA==
```

Using something like:

```
def getAttachmentFromMailMessage(mailId, headers):
    url  = inboxFolderPricingFiles + '/' + mailId + '/' +'attachments'
    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers = headers)
    content = json.loads(response.text)['value'][0]['contentBytes']
    txtString = base64.b64decode(content).decode('utf-8')
    return txtString
```

Returns :

```
this is some test text
```

But when I get the `content-bytes` of the `.zip` file the API returns

```
UEsDBAoAAAAAAHZXRlMb8/ygFgAAABYAAAAIAAAAdGVzdC50eHR0aGlzIGlzIHNvbWUgdGVzdCB0ZXh0UEsBAj8ACgAAAAAAdldGUxvz/KAWAAAAFgAAAAgAJAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAHRlc3QudHh0CgAgAAAAAAABABgAv57iEEW61wG/nuIQRbrXAcZ34hBFutcBUEsFBgAAAAABAAEAWgAAADwAAAAAAA==
```

Using the same code as above:

```
def getAttachmentFromMailMessage(mailId, headers):
    url  = inboxFolderPricingFiles + '/' + mailId + '/' +'attachments'
    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers = headers)
    content = json.loads(response.text)['value'][0]['contentBytes']
    txtString = base64.b64decode(content).decode('utf-8')
    return txtString
```

I get an error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 15: invalid continuation byte
```

Given I don't have a "file-like" object to deal with and instead need to use the returned `content-bytes` from the API I'm unsure how to make this work...

Comment: There is `io.BytesIO` to wrap bytes into a file-like object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the attachment is a zip file, then the bytes you get will be the contents of the zip file. You can wrap those bytes with `io.BytesIO` to create a file-like object and then pass that file-like object to [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) to properly read the contents of the zip file. Here is a modify version of your function that should work in this scenario.

```py
import zipfile

def getAttachmentFromMailMessage(mailId, headers):
    url  = inboxFolderPricingFiles + '/' + mailId + '/' +'attachments'
    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers = headers)
    content = json.loads(response.text)['value'][0]['contentBytes']
    content_bytes = base64.b64decode(content)
    fd = io.BytesIO(content_bytes)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(fd) as myzip:
        first_file = myzip.infolist()[0]
        with myzip.open(first_file) as myfile:
            txtString = myfile.read().decode("utf-8")
    return txtString
```